# Seeds and kitniyot derivatives on Pesach

Tags: passover, kitniyos-semigrain-legume

During the 60's and 70's, I recall being able to use peanut oil on Pesach. Also, we had sesame / honey candy bars (they might have been from Joyva.) All of a sudden, we can't use sesame seeds, or any seeds for that matter! (though, I have seen ground cumin which is from a seed.)
So 2 questions in one: - when / how did peanut oil which is a kitniyot "derivative" become prohibited?
Why are "seeds" included in the kitniyot prohibition. What is the definition of a "seed"? Almost every fruit and vegetable is from a seed. Are pumpkin "seeds" prohibited, too?